# AngularJS button ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="todoController">
  <div class="section hero">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="three columns">
            <li>
              <button class="button button-primary" ng-click="btnClick(first)">Data 1</button>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="nine columns">
          <h4>{{dataText}}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);
app.controller('todoController', function ($scope) {
      $scope.dataText = "";
      $scope.btnClick = function (num){
        dataText = "This is data from the " + num + " button."
      };
  });
```

When I click the button, I would expect the ng-click to initiate and call the function in the controller, but when I click nothing happens, the text on the screen doesn't change or anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is 'first' referencing?  ng-click="btnClick(first)"

Comment: Oh I meant to have it pass a string like "first" the string

Comment: In that case use ng-click="btnClick('first')"

Comment: I just changed it to that but for some reason it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no variable named first in your html,

```
 <li>
   <button class="button button-primary" ng-click="btnClick(first)">Data 1</button>
 </li>
```

Instead of that, Pass it as a string

```
 <li>
   <button class="button button-primary" ng-click="btnClick('first')>Data 1</button>
 </li>
```

Also change the line like this,

```
  $scope.btnClick = function (num){
    $scope.dataText = "This is data from the " + num + " button."
  };
```

Here is the working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/HEidxYjteFAJsZYqFNA9?p=preview)